# JavaScript Change Text using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm struggling with this ... should be simple, not sure what I'm doing wrong.

I need to replace some text using a JavaScript function.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="dd" name="agenda-nestable" id="nestable">
  <ol id="agenda-root" class="dd-list">
    <li class="dd-item" data-type="section" data-id="5455" id="5455">
      <div class="dd-handle">
        <span style="font-weight: bold">Roll Call</span>
        &nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp;&nbsp;Owner: <span>Philip&nbsp;Tenn</span>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ol>
</div>
```

**JavaScript**:

```
function changeName(name) {
    var sectionHtml = $(this).find(".dd-handle").first().html();
  // Get the Name of the Owner
  currentOwner = $(sectionHtml).last("span").text();
  // Change it
  $(sectionHtml).last("span").text(name);
  $(this).find(".dd-handle").first().html(sectionHtml);    
}
```

**Plunk:**

https://plnkr.co/edit/RUt7oF6pmAfKHN5Rh28n?p=preview

Comment: Please make your runnable [mcve] **here on site** using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button). *Edit:* And the questions below are why. You didn't show that in the question, which must be self-contained on-site.

Comment: How are you calling `changeName`?  What's `this` in that context?

Comment: Using `html()` to convert DOM elements to an HTML string only to then us `$()` on that string to create DOM elements again makes no sense.

Comment: As @T.J.Crowder  mentions, you've probably already explained on your plnkr how it works, but I've not looked there because it's off-site.

Comment: Also demo seems oversimplified since you only have one item which can clearly be targeted by an id. Not very clear what higher level objective is

Comment: hi try this :  $(".dd-handle span:last").text(name);

Comment: **Updated:** Next, don't call .html() that will give you a string, disconnected from the html itself and you won't be able to use jquery on it. edit - looked at plnkr, method is called via an onlick, giving:  `$(event.target).closest(".dd").find(".dd-handle").first().find("span‌​").text(name)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work for you:

```js
function changeName(name) {
  const ownerEl = document.querySelector('.dd-handle > span:last-child');
  ownerEl.innerText = name;
}
```

```html
<div class="dd" name="agenda-nestable" id="nestable">
  <ol id="agenda-root" class="dd-list">
    <li class="dd-item" data-type="section" data-id="5455" id="5455">
      <div class="dd-handle">
        <span style="font-weight: bold">Roll Call</span> &nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp;&nbsp;Owner: <span>Philip&nbsp;Tenn</span>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ol>
</div>
<p>
  <button onclick='changeName("Jane Doe")'>Change Name</button>
</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

If the goal is to change the name at the end (where you curently have `Philip Tenn`), it's a lot simpler than that: :-)

```
function changeName(name) {
  $(this).find(".dd-handle span").last().text(name);
}
```

...where I'm assuming `changeName` is called with `this` referring to `#nestable`:

```js
$("#nestable").on("click", function() {
  changeName.call(this, "Joe Bloggs");
});

function changeName(name) {
  $(this).find(".dd-handle span").last().text(name);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="dd" name="agenda-nestable" id="nestable">
  <ol id="agenda-root" class="dd-list">
    <li class="dd-item" data-type="section" data-id="5455" id="5455">
      <div class="dd-handle">
        <span style="font-weight: bold">Roll Call</span>
        &nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp;&nbsp;Owner: <span>Philip&nbsp;Tenn</span>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ol>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

try this.
use id in span

```
<span style="font-weight: bold">Roll Call</span>
&nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp;&nbsp;Owner: <span id="owner_name">Philip&nbsp;Tenn</span>
            </div>
```

and then in code

```
  $("#owner_name").html("").html(sectionHtml);
```

rest remains the same.